Does a free range rule infringe upon a fixed rule?
Patented invention / process / system:
1) X is a predefined number known to the user.
2) If A and B occurs, then the user wins X balls.

Potential infringer
1) X and Y are predefined numbers known to the user.
2) If A and B occurs, then the user will win a number of balls between X and Y.

Does the second invention infringe upon the first?

Did the second “invention” get granted as a patent?

The second is not a patent. But it is an implementation currently being used. So the question is whether or not the first patent blocks this potential implementation.

I am not a lawyer. That said, I would guess that the second implementation infringes on the patent only when the user wins X balls. Thus if the user wins X+1 ball, X-1 ball or any other number of balls except X, it doesn't infringe. Adding a step to a patented process doesn't avoid infringement if each and every step of a claim is implemented. Thus in step one adding knowledge of Y doesn't mean you don't implement step one since the user knows about X. Likewise in step two, if you reward the user with X balls you implement step two.
In real life, things tend to be more complex and potentially more ambiguous.

Let's instead suppose that in the first patent, the X is determined by the APP. In the potential infringing invention, X and Y are randomly generated. Would this still infringe?

@BearBileFarmingisTorture It all depends on the wording of the claim. If you implement each and every step in a claim you open yourself up to an infringement suit. As I said in the answer, just adding something additional doesn't protect you.
